# Using facebook to authenticate to github

Tags: javascript, java, rest, reactjs, authentication

is it possible to authenticate to github using facebook and then do some github-request?

Everything what I can find is just about to authenticate to facebook and nothing is about github

Clarification:
I'm trying to use a Facebook account to access Github

Comment: you might want to clarify if you mean you're trying to use a Facebook account to access Github, or trying to use a GitHub account to do something with Facebook(such as an API call)

Comment: Clarification added thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Without a ton of information in the question, I would recommend you look into Facebooks oauth capibilities: http://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/facebook.html

Comment: Clarification added